# First time my assertion fails the error message appears

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have simple C++ code (Console app) in Visual studio.
My main function contains assertions.
If I debug/run my code and some assertion fails the message box appers:

***Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library***

*Debug error*

*Program: \C:\Users....\something.exe*

*abort() has been called*

*Please retry to debug application*

I have console where it failed (assert(false)). But it is annoying. If I press the retry button the whole code runs again and message box will not appear this time. The code stops in assertion that fails with note: "Exception thrown" and everything is okay.

I tried to solve this but i didn't find anything useful. Could you please help me? I am C++ begginer and I am terrified using debugger for bigger projects I will work on later.

Thank you!

Comment: "...and everything is okay." ? What is the assertion that fails?

Comment: Sounds like you are invoking the debugger on demand, in which case this behaviour is normal (although it doesn't 'run the whole code again').

Comment: Assertion should fails. My problem is that in first run there is a message box with error.

The behaviour is normal when I delete my problem assertion (assert(false) in this case). Or when I press RETRY and the code runs again. Then it fails but no message box appears which is the behaviour I want.

Comment: You know, I've never tried this. Add your example code to the question and I'll throw it into VS 2015, most recent I've got, and see what happens. Maybe retying after you've already hit the assertion just tries to continue, rather than restarting the program,  from where you left off and Ka-BOOM!

Comment: My example code is this (below)
There is nothing wrong with it. It fails and it should fail. The message box is the problem and I am sure it has nothing to do with code itself. 
int main()
{
    assert(false);
    return 0;
}

Comment: I am sorry. I have been wrong when I said the code runs again. It does not, it seems. But still not understand why the error appears. It is annoying. After I press retry normal "exception thrown" appears in visual studio. But why the message box shows?

Comment: As I say, this is normal.  If you want to break into the debugger straightaway, run the program under the debugger in the first place.